# how to edit aliases

Tags: bash, terminal, alias

I just started looking into aliases and I already created a couple aliases before reading how to write alias commands into files so you can easily edit them.  If you just directly run the command `alias thing=whatever_you_want_to_happen`, how can you edit/remove this alias? Is there a command to run that will show you all the aliases you have created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [H]ow can you edit/remove [an] alias?

Use unalias:

```
unalias thing
```

To remove all aliases at once, you can use the `-a` switch.

> Is there a command to run that will show you all the aliases you have created?

Just execute the plain command:

```
alias
```

Sources:

- [man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)
- [alias Man Page | SS64.com](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html)